# Buffer says that it is not part of dataset after being input with BIND

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have a dataset which I am passing to another procedure using `BIND`. In that procedure, I need to define a second dataset on a subset of the first dataset's temp-tables; however, Progress does not let me put the same buffer in two datasets so I must define the second dataset on new named buffers of the old temp-tables. However, when I access the handle of the new named buffer, Progress is telling me that the buffer is not a member of a dataset. (The `DATASET` attribute of the buffer handle gives `?`.)

Here are my procedures:

Proc1.p:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttShifts NO-UNDO 
    FIELD shiftid AS INT
    FIELD emp AS CHAR.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttTasks NO-UNDO 
    FIELD taskid AS INT
    FIELD shiftid AS INT.

DEFINE DATASET dsShifts
    FOR ttShifts, ttTasks
    DATA-RELATION relTask FOR ttShifts, ttTasks
        RELATION-FIELDS(ttShifts.shiftid, ttTasks.shiftid) NESTED.

DEFINE VARIABLE lcJson AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hProc2 AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN lcJson = '~{"dsShifts":~{"ttShifts":[~{"shiftid":101,"emp":"Stewart","ttTasks":[~{"taskid":333,"shiftid":101}]}]}}'.

DATASET dsShifts:READ-JSON("LONGCHAR", lcJson).

RUN proc2.p PERSISTENT SET hProc2.
RUN bindDsShifts IN hProc2 (INPUT DATASET dsShifts BIND).
RUN runProc IN hProc2.
DELETE PROCEDURE hProc2.
```

Proc2.p:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttShifts NO-UNDO REFERENCE-ONLY
    FIELD shiftid AS INT
    FIELD emp AS CHAR.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttTasks NO-UNDO REFERENCE-ONLY 
    FIELD taskid AS INT
    FIELD shiftid AS INT.

DEFINE DATASET dsShiftsExt
    REFERENCE-ONLY
    FOR ttShifts, ttTasks
    DATA-RELATION relTask FOR ttShifts, ttTasks
        RELATION-FIELDS(ttShifts.shiftid, ttTasks.shiftid) NESTED.

DEFINE BUFFER bfShifts FOR ttShifts.
DEFINE DATASET dsShifts FOR bfShifts.

PROCEDURE bindDsShifts:
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER DATASET FOR dsShiftsExt BIND.
END.

PROCEDURE runProc:
    DEFINE VARIABLE hDsShifts AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE hBuf AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
    ASSIGN 
        hDsShifts = DATASET dsShifts:HANDLE
        hBuf = hDsShifts:GET-BUFFER-HANDLE (1).
    MESSAGE VALID-HANDLE(hBuf:DATASET) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    /* here I expect YES but I see NO */
END.
```

Can someone explain to me why at the end, the `hBuf:DATASET` is not a valid handle?

(In my actual code, I am trying to do `ATTACH-DATA-SOURCE` which fails because the buffer is supposedly not part of a dataset.)

I am running OpenEdge 11.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code on OpenEdge 11.3 and OpenEdge 11.7 (64 bit).

OpenEdge 11.3 returns FALSE and OpenEdge 11.7 returns TRUE. So this might look like a bug that was fixed in the meantime. If you need details (and maybe a hotfix when upgrading is no option, you should contact Progress Software technical support).